# $lookup from nested array without overwriting array

Tags: mongodb

My collection looks like:

```
collectionName: {
    _id: ObjectId("..."),
    thing1: 'whatever',
    thing2: 100,
    arrayOfThings: [{
        item1: 'something'
        item2: 200,
        other_id: ObjectId("..."),
    ]}
}
```

Essentially I want to be able to find this entry by its _id, then for each of the items in the arrayOfThings I want to add an "other" field which is the entry in my other collection with the _id in "other_id".

Resulting in:

```
collectionName: {
    _id: ObjectId("..."),
    thing1: 'whatever',
    thing2: 100,
    arrayOfThings: [{
        item1: 'something'
        item2: 200,
        other_id: ObjectId("..."),
        other: {
            otherField1: 'random data',
            otherField2: 3000
    ]}
}
```

Everything I've tried either overwrites the entire arrayOfThings array with the array that is returned from the other collection or returns several objects, each with only one entry in the arrayOfThings array by doing something like this:

```
aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: req.params._id }},
    { $unwind: "$arrayOfThings" },
    { $lookup: { from: "otherCollection", localField: "arrayOfThings.other_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "arrayOfThings.other" }},
]);
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: are you getting result? if yes then what are you getting in result?

Comment: With the example I posted it returns several collection objects (= the number of items in arrayOfThings) with the arrayOfThings field only containing one of the objects that should be in the array. Basically instead of arrayOfThings containing the desired array I get an array of collections each containing one of the items I want stored in arrayOfThings. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match`, `$unwind` and `$lookup` stages remain same
- `$addFields` to get first element from lookup result
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct `arrayOfThings`, and get other fields using `$first`

```
db.col1.aggregate([
  // $match, $unwind and $lookup skipping,
  {
    $addFields: {
      "arrayOfThings.other": { $arrayElemAt: ["$arrayOfThings.other", 0] }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      arrayOfThings: { $push: "$arrayOfThings" },
      thing1: { $first: "$thing1" },
      thing2: { $first: "$thing2" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jv8flG_hIhe)